# sharing grid contents acrosss Pivot tems

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot

I'd like to know if it is possible to share grid contents across different pivotitems so that only some extra information is added to another pivot item in Windows Phone. if possible please let me know.

To elaborate, I have a customer input form on one pivot control, and the next pivot page is for a special kind of customer so he has extra fields and we want to make the customer feel different, but the logic is pretty much the same.

can I reference the same contentGrid in another PivotItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But you can create a custom UserControl, and bind it with the same data.

Here's a [guide about UserControls](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-a-WP7-Custom-Control-in-7-Steps)

Answer (score 0):

You can put this `contentGrid` into a `DataTemplate`, and then have different pivot page referencing the same `DataTemplate`. You will probably need to create a `ContentControl` for each of your pivot page, something like this,

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerDataTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="contentGrid">
        ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CustomerOneData}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerDataTemplate}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CustomerTwoData}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerDataTemplate}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

Then you have two choices. First you can define all your controls inside the DataTemplate then show/hide some certain controls based on the customer type. Or you can just create this `DataTemplate` for shared controls, and then put those extra ones outside the `ContentControl`.

Comment: Thanks, I did achieve it using UserControl though. will look into this later.